# How to compute the norm of a linear mapping?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology

Is there hints for this exercise from a topology book of mine? First there is a notation that if $A:E\to F$ is a linear mapping between norm spaces then we denote $$|A|=\sup\{|Ax|:|x|\leq 1\}.$$ Now, suppose that $A:\mathbb R^2\to \mathbb R^2$ is a linear mapping such that $$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 3\\2 & 4\end{pmatrix}. $$ Compute $|A|$. I had difficulties even to start. Do I need eigenvectors? I was given the answer $|A|=\sqrt{15+\sqrt{221}}$.

Comment: What is the norm $|.|$. Is it the same for the spaces $E$ and $F$ ?

Comment: In that chapter $E$ and $F$ are arbitrary norm spaces but in this problem $E=F=\mathbb R^2$

Comment: You just have to compute $\max\limits_{\|x\|_E\leq 1} {\|Ax\|_F}=\max\limits_{\|x\|_E\leq 1}{\|(x_1+3x_2,2x_1+4x_2)\|_F}$

Comment: Now it depends on which norm you will use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $|\cdot|$ is the Euclidean norm on both of $E $ and $F $, then $|A|$ is the biggest singular value, i.e. the square root of the largest eigenvalue of $A^TA $.

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer:** The other answers are more concise and the OP has already accepted one, but I had already started writing mine, so I went with it.

---

Note that the norm of $A$ is defined as the supremum of a particular set, namely the image of the closed unit ball under $|A|$ (which is a composition of $A$ with $|\cdot|$), $|A|(B_1(0))$. Note that $|A|(B_1(0))$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$.

Then all we need more is the definition of supremum of a subset of $\mathbb{R}$. If $S(\neq\emptyset)\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is bounded from above, (by the supremum axiom) it has a least upper bound $\sup{A}$. This means that $A$ has no member greater than this number, and any number smaller than this number cannot be an upper bound for $A$. There is a practical way of characterizing $\sup{A}$: $\alpha=\sup{A}$ if and only if the following two conditions hold:

- $\forall a\in A:a\leq\alpha$
- $\forall \varepsilon>0,\exists a_\varepsilon\in A: \alpha-\varepsilon<a_\varepsilon\leq\alpha.$